# How to use AND operator in update operation for where clause in Android Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I am trying to update my table, But It gives me error how can I use AND operator in Where clause for update?

here is my code;

```
public static void updateData(long lday, String id, String usedamount, String trashedamount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();          

        updatedValues.put("usedamount", usedamount);
        updatedValues.put("trashedamount",trashedamount);

        // HERE I WANT TO USE AND OPERATOR FOR DAY AND ID
        // this and operator gives error


        db.update("info_table", updatedValues, DAY + "=" + lday AND ID + "=" + id, null);

    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: it does not update this code
db.update("info_table", updatedValues, DAY + "=" + lday AND ID + "=" + id, null);

Comment: is it a compiler error?

Comment: Edit your question and add the exact error message you receive.

Comment: i mean what exception you are getting here? share the exception

Comment: it says Multiple markers at this line
 - The primitive type long of lday does not have a field 
  ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AND` operator needs to be in quotation marks

```
public static void updateData(long lday, String id, String usedamount, String trashedamount) {
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();          
    updatedValues.put("usedamount", usedamount);
    updatedValues.put("trashedamount",trashedamount);

    db.update("info_table", updatedValues, DAY + "=" + lday + " AND " + ID + "=" + id, null);
}
```

Comment: yes it is fine but it needs 9 minutes to accept the answer :) thanks a lot.